# How to add bouncing to a switch in LTspice?

Tags: relay, ltspice, debounce, reed-switch

Is it possible to add bouncing for a switch in LTspice?
Below is a reed relay simulated in LTspice.
I can set the on and off resistances but is there a workaround to create bouncing as well?

[image]

With no bouncing, the simulation of the relay outputs the following clean output:

[image]

By bouncing I mean something similar to this:

[image]

The reason I'm asking this question I want to see if I can implement an RC debouncing circuit in simulation which works before implementing.

Comment: Do you know the bounce time interval ?   You can simulate with triangle plus %10% sine f into comparator and adjust f and %

Comment: what does "%10% sine f" mean?

Comment: SNR of 10:1 for triangle signal with high f noise using just a sine wave or use filtered random noise , no matter or use whatever your specs for immunity are... 3:1 below xx Hz stray line noise plus bounce then you can simulate any noisy switch

Comment: follow these guidelines for surge limiting http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=13C3236_AppNote&DocType=CS&DocLang=EN

Comment: Record some real life bouncing and provide it as a pwl file

Comment: @PlasmaHH: This looks like the best answer to me - you can create some really wicked contact bouncing with a PWL file :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use another of the VCSW elements and a different voltage source to control it. Place those in parallel to your existing VCSW. Then set the timing so that it *delays* until it gets close to an edge you want to test. Something like this:

[image: LTspice simulation of bounce]

I've used .PARAM to set F to 500 Hz. The left side MYSW emulates the 500 Hz period of the reed relay. The right side emulates bounce (I divided by an additional 200 to make the pulses short.) Take note of the .22/F delay. The left side uses a delay of .25/F. By making the bounce switch delay a little less, this gets the pulses to start taking place a little beforehand. I also cap the number of cycles to 6 here. But you can adjust as you want.

EDIT: Here are the pictures of the simulator I set up in LTspice, below. You may need to adjust the filter capacitor to reduce the swing to stay within the 4V hysteresis limits. Also, your LED will affect this.

Truly, this would be a LOT easier with a micro. Or using a 7555 as a schmitt trigger, I suspect. This is really overly-complex.

[image: REED AND BOUNCE]

[image: ACTIVE DRIVE AND INDICATOR]

[image: FILTER]

[image: SCHMITT]

Comment: i tried to simulate your suggestions here is the whole part of  the switching circuit: https://s22.postimg.org/jjntvz5a9/glcrt.png only for the first switch action i see: https://s11.postimg.org/s8kwb9eb7/glcth.png but thats it. the switching doesnt repeat on and off: https://s18.postimg.org/43xdn2cih/longlcrt.png am i doing something wrong here? thanks in advance

Comment: @user16307 Added some notes.

Comment: @jonk You don't need an extra switch, just add the second source to the inverting input of the first. Or, if you want to save one more node, make the main source a voltage source with `Rser=1` and add a parallel current source across it as the equivalent of the second voltage source. Or you could go fancier by adding a `pulse 0 1 0 1m 1m 5 10` driving a lowpass `LC` with `1 Rser=0.2` for `L` and `25m Rpar=200` for `C`, driving a switch with `vt=0.425 vh=-0.1` (or whatever values you see fit). Or a "do all" behavioural source, or an exponentially decaying sine with `trigger`. Ah well... :-)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I just wanted to use the same method that the OP would immediately understand (prior communication.) I like your additions. Hopefully, the OP will try them!

Comment: @jonk i spent long time to figure out why in my simulation the bounce doesn't repeat after the first cycle still no progress o my side. here what i simulate and i double checked what you have written and the connections are the same with yours: https://s10.postimg.org/fe4h4s92h/jktled.png But I get the following output: https://s9.postimg.org/fkjqgg8i7/jktled_ptsng.png Is that also what you get? Or do you get periodic bounces for each pulse edges?

Comment: @user16307 I didn't intend more than one bounce test, on one of the first edges. A concerned citizen discussed some other ideas. There also is PWL, from a file, if you want. What I showed is just one edge with a set of bouncing at a higher frequency. But just the one. You can move it to different places, though.